# Print object to table onClick - doesnt print until clicked twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Basically what I want to do is have the user click a button to print an object that I've gotten from a web service into a table. This works somewhat, but I have to click the button twice to make it print. 
More detail: The button uses `onClick={this.handleClick}`, inside the handleClick a few things are done, including getting the object in question and storing it in a result variable, then calling addToTable(result).

```
addToTable(result){
this.state.rows.push(
  <TableRow>
   <TableCell> {result.example1} </TableCell>
   <TableCell> {result.example2} </TableCell>
  <TableRow>
 )
this.setState({rows: rows});
}
```

The table itself has a hard coded header line, and refers to rows for the body like:

```
<TableBody>
 {this.state.rows}
</TableBody>
```

I've tried adding a delay onto the addToTable call but this does nothing, I cant work out why I have to click the button twice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging - I found the issue to be common with so many different suggested fixes - none of which worked.

I found that `this.setState` wasn't causing the table to actually update/render. By replacing with `this.forceUpdate();` the table now works correctly. This isn't an idea fix, but for a beginner this is all I could get to work.